# Export content from mail body & export to excel using AppleScript

Tags: excel, email, applescript

I am trying to export an email with a set template so that each of the fields will be placed in a separate Excel column.

So currently all the emails I receive that I need to export get put into a separate folder to the inbox. The email will have the following;

```
Name:
Age:
Email address:
Phone Number:
```

I am looking for a way to run a script that will go through all of the emails in this folder and get the information from each field and place them in columns on Excel, so there will be a name column, age column etc.

Currently I have a script that almost works, but I cannot get it to split the contents of the body of the email.

Currently I will create the Excel document, but I cannot get it to split the body of the email to the separate columns. I have commented a bit of code which will return the fields separated, but only of one email not all of them.

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    set LinkRemoval to make new workbook
    set theSheet to active sheet of LinkRemoval
    set formula of range "F1" of theSheet to "Phone Number"
    set formula of range "E1" of theSheet to "Email address"
    set formula of range "D1" of theSheet to "Age"
    set formula of range "C1" of theSheet to "Name"
    set formula of range "B1" of theSheet to "From"
    set formula of range "A1" of theSheet to "Date"

end tell

tell application "Mail"
    set theRow to 2
    set theAccount to "Gmail"
    set theMessages to messages of mailbox "signups" of account "Gmail"
    set mySelection to selection
    set myMail to first item of mySelection
    set myLines to every paragraph of (content of myMail)
    repeat with aMessage in theMessages
        my SetDate(date received of aMessage, theRow, theSheet)
        my SetFrom(sender of aMessage, theRow, theSheet)
        my SetMessageC(content of aMessage, theRow, theSheet)
        my SetMessageD(content of aMessage, theRow, theSheet)
        my SetMessageE(content of aMessage, theRow, theSheet)
        my SetMessageF(content of aMessage, theRow, theSheet)
        set theRow to theRow + 1
    end repeat
end tell

(* set myEvent to ExtractfromRichText(myLines) -- parse the paragraphs to make a record {EName, ERoom,EStart,EEnd}

on ExtractfromRichText(LocalLines) -- convert the rich text with fixed format into a data set
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {":", return & linefeed, return, linefeed} -- to remove all rich text end lines
    repeat with aLine in LocalLines
        try
            if text item 1 of aLine contains "Name" then set Name to text item 2 of aLine
            if text item 1 of aLine contains "Age" then set Age to text item 2 of aLine
            if text item 1 of aLine contains "Email Address is" then set emailAddress to text item 2 of aLine
            if text item 1 of aLine contains "Phone Number" then set phoneNumber to text item 2 of aLine
        on error -- unexpected format
            log "error"
            return {EName:""} -- not proper email format for calendar events. return empty name
        end try
    end repeat
    return {Name:Name, Age:Age, Email Address:emailAddress, Phone Number:phoneNumber}
end ExtractfromRichText *)

on SetDate(theDate, theRow, theSheet)
    tell application "Microsoft Excel"
        set theRange to "A" & theRow
        set number format of column 1 to "dd/mm/yyyy"
        set formula of range theRange of theSheet to theDate
    end tell
end SetDate

on SetFrom(theSender, theRow, theSheet)
    tell application "Microsoft Excel"
        set theRange to "B" & theRow
        set formula of range theRange of theSheet to theSender
    end tell
end SetFrom

on SetMessageC(theMessage, theRow, theSheet)
    tell application "Microsoft Excel"
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {":", return & linefeed, return, linefeed}
        set theRange to "C" & theRow
        set number format of column 3 to "Text"
        set formula of range theRange of theSheet to theMessage
    end tell
end SetMessageC

on SetMessageD(theMessage, theRow, theSheet)
    tell application "Microsoft Excel"
        set theRange to "D" & theRow
        set number format of column 4 to "Text"
        set formula of range theRange of theSheet to theMessage
    end tell
end SetMessageD

on SetMessageE(theMessage, theRow, theSheet)
    tell application "Microsoft Excel"
        set theRange to "E" & theRow
        set number format of column 5 to "Text"
        set formula of range theRange of theSheet to theMessage
    end tell
end SetMessageE

on SetMessageF(theMessage, theRow, theSheet)
    tell application "Microsoft Excel"
        set theRange to "F" & theRow
        set number format of column 6 to "Text"
        set formula of range theRange of theSheet to theMessage
    end tell
end SetMessageF
```